# Force.com Explorer with OAuth complient environments

Tags: api, oauth2, workbench, force.com-explorer

As I can see (correct me if I am wrong), Force.com Explorer can't be used for Salesforce environments where forcing of OAuth 2.0 compliance is set to true ? Is there some newer version of this application that is OAuth 2.0 complaint ?

As an solution there can be used only [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com)

Comment: What do you mean by 'Salesforce environments where forcing of OAuth 2.0 compliance is set to true'? What setting is this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest version, that's it.
You can use the Force.com IDE to explore your database as well. (the schema)
You can construct queries by selecting the appropriate fields and relationships.

Comment: I have 0.58A version, that is latest. It is not OAuth 2.0 complaint.

Comment: The one option is the Force.com IDE